# Python pandas produces incorrect csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.8

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "last_updated":1591198411,
  "ttl":0,
  "data":{
     "cars":[
        {
           "car_id":"c71dd6a3-5bbe-4d74-b73d-83dda7e4b96b",
           "lat":38.93067,
           "lon":-77.01845,
           "is_reserved":0,
           "is_disabled":0
        },
        {
           "car_id":"87573243-6339-464e-b28a-34fb1de1719f",
           "lat":38.86218,
           "lon":-76.98284,
           "is_reserved":0,
           "is_disabled":0
       }
    ]
 }
}
```

I want to convert it to csv using python pandas. I tried the following code:

```
with open(data.json, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f_input:
    df = pandas.read_json(f_input)
    df.to_csv(data.csv, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Unfortunately, the CSV I get is incorrect: All the "data" field is in one single cell. I don't want to lose the "last_updated" and "ttl" fields.
This is the result I would like to have:

```
"last_updated","ttl","data__cars__car_id","data__cars__lat","data__cars__lon","data__cars__is_reserved","data__cars__is_disabled"
"1591198411","0","c71dd6a3-5bbe-4d74-b73d-83dda7e4b96b","38.93067","-77.01845","0","0"
"","","87573243-6339-464e-b28a-34fb1de1719f","38.86218","-76.98284","0","0"
```

What would be the correct way to do this, please?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you expect as a `.csv`? Do you want one row per car_id?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the orient perhaps.

```
pd.read_json(_, orient='orient_type')
```

Visit pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) for all orient types and more parameters.

Comment: I tried all the possible typ/orient, without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you haven't solved it yet:

```
with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['data', 'cars'], meta=['ttl', 'last_updated'])
print(df)

                                 car_id       lat       lon  is_reserved  is_disabled ttl last_updated
0  c71dd6a3-5bbe-4d74-b73d-83dda7e4b96b  38.93067 -77.01845            0            0   0   1591198411
1  87573243-6339-464e-b28a-34fb1de1719f  38.86218 -76.98284            0            0   0   1591198411
```